# Predicting New ImageNet Pictures

Tags: keras

I'm having problems predicting new images based on the ImageNet database where objects are placed on different backgrounds. Predicting the classes work well on various models (ResNets and VGG) but it doesn't work at all for Densenets and Inception. I'm thinking this is related to the labels but I can't figure out what's wrong exactly.

The labels are ordered from 0 to 999 (divided in maps) and are in the same order as the original dataset.

I've changed to labels to the other format (e.g. n02676566). This didn't work for DenseNet (ResNets still worked fine).

Code:

```
model = keras.applications.densenet.DenseNet201(weights='imagenet', classes=1000)

labels = [str(i) for i in range(0,1000)]

generator_imagenet = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(path, target_size(224,224), batch_size=64, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True, classes=labels)

resnet18_model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

resnet18_model.evaluate_generator(generator_imagenet)
```

Output ResNet 152:

> Found 243 images belonging to 1000 classes. [1.6771895689238245,
>   0.5679012397189199]
>
> Output DenseNet 201:
>
> Found 243 images belonging to 1000 classes. [15.938421453468102, 0.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to preprocess the images using the `preprocess_input` function provided with each `keras_applications` model.
Add the following changes.

```
keras.applications.densenet import preprocess_input
generator_imagenet = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input).flow_from_directory(path, 
                                                          target_size(224,224),
                                                          batch_size=64,
                                                          class_mode='categorical', 
                                                          shuffle=True, 
                                                          classes=labels)
```